# How can i make the style sheet rendering in expressjs/ejs common?

Tags: node.js, typescript, templates, ejs

I am using ejs in node for creating an app. And in my ejs, when I navigate from one page to another I have to render the header also to have the styles.

How can I make this common for all pages?

````
<title>Static Website </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="active-menu">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/abc.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/def.css"> ```

I don't want load styles on every routing. Render all the styles on first page itself
````

Answer (score 0):

ejs will render the page every time you refresh the page, so you need to put every css you need. you can pass var that say if a css is needed ex: isDefNedded = true and make a if statement in your ejs header

Comment: so you meant to say, I have to load all the css in every page. Doesn't that make a performance issue?

Comment: Yes,you have to and it's does not change performance that much.